# Extracting text from char in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am a beginner C-programmer. Recently I've been trying to practise using string functions in C.

As such, I wrote the following program:

MessageDetector.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char a[100] = "Alex:HeyGoodMorning!:1911hrs:0:1012:2017:::";
    char *p = strtok(a,":");
    char n[20];

    int i = 1;

    while(p != NULL) {
        strcpy(n,p);
        p = strtok(NULL,":"); //limit to characters before semi-colon
        i++;

        if (i = 2) { //after 2 occurrences of the semi-colon. print a string
            printf("%s\n",n);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of my program is as follows:

```
Alex
```

However, I would like the program to output

```
HeyGoodMorning!
```

What are the changes I should make to the above program? Your help is greatfully appreciated

Comment: `if(i=2)` should be `if(i==2)`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Oh my goodness ! I should have noticed. Thank you for your help ! I'll be sure to practise due diligence in the future. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You are welcome! If your program works now, please click [delete] link.

Comment: If you turned on compiler warnings it would have warned you about the line causing the problem.

Comment: Consider using `if (2 == i)` to prevent such an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the variable `i` with 0 and use comparison instead of assignment in this condition

```
int i = 0;
//...
if(i == 2){//
```

Take into account that the first call of `strcpy` is redundant.

In fact you could do the same without a loop.  For example

```
char a[100] = "Alex:HeyGoodMorning!:1911hrs:0:1012:2017:::";
char *p;

if ((p = strtok(a, ":")) && (p = strtok(NULL, ":")))
{
    puts(p);
}
```